# Is every derived category (isomorphic to a category) locally small?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, derived-categories

Given an abelian category $A$, we can form its derived category $D(A)$ [as follows](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+category):

1. Start with the category of (co)chain complexes in $A$.
2. Construct the homotopy category $K(A)$ by keeping the objects, but defining the morphisms by quotienting by (co)chain homotopy.
3. Localize with respect to quasi-isomorphisms, which admits both-sided calculus of fractions.

Therefore, given any (co)chain complexes $X$ and $Y$ in $A$, we have:
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{D(A)}(X,Y) = \varinjlim_{s: Y \to Y'} \operatorname{Hom}_{K(A)}(X, Y')$$
where the limit is taken over all quasi-isomorphisms $s: Y \to Y'$. (Gabriel–Zisman, *Calculus of fractions and homotopy theory*, Proposition I.2.4)

My question is: **Can the filtered colimit always be taken to be a set?**

Comment: $D^+(A)$ is better behaved, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Doesn't [the counter-example by Jeremy Rickard](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4124739/328173) work for $D^+$ as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $R=k[x_i\mid i\in I]$ be a polynomial "algebra" in variables indexed by a proper class $I$. [I put "algebra" in quotation marks, as of course $R$ is not a set.]

Let $A$ be the category of finite dimensional $R$-modules (i.e., finite dimensional vector spaces with a class of commuting endomorphisms indexed by $I$). This is a perfectly good locally small abelian category.

Let $k$ be the one-dimensional $R$-module on which every $x_i$ acts as zero.

For each $i\in I$, there is an extension of $k$ by $k$ on which $x_i$ acts as $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and on which $x_j$ acts as zero for $j\neq i$. These extensions are clearly pairwise nonequivalent, and so
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{D(A)}(k,k[1])=\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(k,k)$$
is not a set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This might be a stupid question, but how do you make each object of $A$ a set? i.e. How do you encode the information of "finite dimensional vector spaces with a class of commuting endomorphisms indexed by $I$" in a set?

Comment: @KennyLau If that worries you, then you can adapt the definition of the objects to require that $x_i$ acts as zero for all but finitely many $i$. So then an object is encoded as a finite dimensional vector space, a finite subset of $I$, and an endomorphism for each element of that subset.

Comment: @KennyLau The example in my answer is essentially the same as one that appears in Freyd’s book on Abelian Categories, where his definition of a category for foundational purposes is as a class of morphisms with a partially defined composition, where the objects only emerge as the identity morphisms.